# Difference between static and dynamic schedule in OpenMP in C

Tags: c, openmp

I've got two similar codes.

First

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(g) private(i) schedule(dynamic, 1)
for(i = (*g).actualNumberOfChromosomes; i < (*g).maxNumberOfChromosomes; i++)
{
    AddCrossoverChromosome(g, i); // it doesnt change actualNumberOfChromosomes
    #pragma omp atomic
    (*g).actualNumberOfChromosomes++;
}
```

Second

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(g) private(i) schedule(static, 1)
for(i = (*g).actualNumberOfChromosomes; i < (*g).maxNumberOfChromosomes; i++)
{
    AddCrossoverChromosome(g, i); // it doesnt change actualNumberOfChromosomes
    #pragma omp atomic
    (*g).actualNumberOfChromosomes++;
}
```

The only difference is in the first line. First code works fine, but the second one crashes. Why?

Problem is somewhere in `actualNumberOfChromosomes`, but I would like to understand why, and not just solve this. I could solve this by creating addition variable `p` and assigning `actualNumberOfChromosomes` to it and changing the loop so that `i` was equal to `p`.

Comment: Could you detail why the second program crashes? Has the pointer, g, been corrupted? And, when it crashed? You could printf the value of i. I need more information to understand this problem. You may print out some variables for each iteration and each thread.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that this code is not OpenMP compliant and non-compliant programs have "unspecified" behavior.  If you look at the OpenMP API V3.0 spec, section 2.5.1 Loop Construct, under the description it states:

> The iteration count for each associated loop is computed before entry to the outermost
>   loop. If execution of any associated loop changes any of the values used to compute
>   any of the iteration counts then the behavior is unspecified.

The big difference between a schedule type of static and dynamic, is that with static, the chunks can be somewhat computed and scheduled to threads during compilation, while with dynamic it is done during run-time (requiring more locking).

Answer (score 16):

The difference between **`static`** schedule type and **`dynamic`** schedule type is that with `static` the chunks can be pre-computed as well as decided how to scheduled to threads during compilation itself, whereas with `dynamic` the same thing is done during run-time.

With the usage of `dynamic`, it involves some complex mechanisms like deadlock handling mechanism, load handling, etc.

You can get some more info at: http://openmp.blogspot.com.