# What's the difference between "static" and "dynamic" schedule in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I started working with OpenMP using C++.

I have two questions:

1. What is `#pragma omp for schedule`?
2. What is the difference between `dynamic` and `static`?

Please, explain with examples.

Comment: I think you have difficulty with the English meaning of schedule. It refers to the way the work, i.e. the individual values of the loop variable, is spread across the threads. `static` means that it is decided at the beginning which thread will do which values, where as `dynamic` means that each thread will work on a chunk of values and then take the next chunk which hasn't been worked on by any thread. The latter allows better balancing (in case the work varies between different values for the loop variable), but requires some communication overhead.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Others have since answered most of the question but I would like to point to some specific cases where a particular scheduling type is more suited than the others. Schedule controls how loop iterations are divided among threads. Choosing the right schedule can have great impact on the speed of the application.

`static` schedule means that iterations blocks are mapped statically to the execution threads in a round-robin fashion. The nice thing with static scheduling is that OpenMP run-time guarantees that if you have two separate loops with the same number of iterations and execute them with the same number of threads using static scheduling, then each thread will receive exactly the same iteration range(s) in both parallel regions. This is quite important on NUMA systems: if you touch some memory in the first loop, it will reside on the NUMA node where the executing thread was. Then in the second loop the same thread could access the same memory location faster since it will reside on the same NUMA node.

Imagine there are two NUMA nodes: node 0 and node 1, e.g. a two-socket Intel Nehalem board with 4-core CPUs in both sockets. Then threads 0, 1, 2, and 3 will reside on node 0 and threads 4, 5, 6, and 7 will reside on node 1:

```
|             | core 0 | thread 0 |
| socket 0    | core 1 | thread 1 |
| NUMA node 0 | core 2 | thread 2 |
|             | core 3 | thread 3 |

|             | core 4 | thread 4 |
| socket 1    | core 5 | thread 5 |
| NUMA node 1 | core 6 | thread 6 |
|             | core 7 | thread 7 |
```

Each core can access memory from each NUMA node, but remote access is slower (1.5x - 1.9x slower on Intel) than local node access. You run something like this:

```
char *a = (char *)malloc(8*4096);

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1) num_threads(8)
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   memset(&a[i*4096], 0, 4096);
```

4096 bytes in this case is the standard size of one memory page on Linux on x86 if huge pages are not used. This code will zero the whole 32 KiB array `a`. The `malloc()` call just reserves virtual address space but does not actually "touch" the physical memory (this is the default behaviour unless some other version of `malloc` is used, e.g. one that zeroes the memory like `calloc()` does). Now this array is contiguous but only in virtual memory. In physical memory half of it would lie in the memory attached to socket 0 and half in the memory attached to socket 1. This is so because different parts are zeroed by different threads and those threads reside on different cores and there is something called *first touch* NUMA policy which means that memory pages are allocated on the NUMA node on which the thread that first "touched" the memory page resides.

```
|             | core 0 | thread 0 | a[0]     ... a[4095]
| socket 0    | core 1 | thread 1 | a[4096]  ... a[8191]
| NUMA node 0 | core 2 | thread 2 | a[8192]  ... a[12287]
|             | core 3 | thread 3 | a[12288] ... a[16383]

|             | core 4 | thread 4 | a[16384] ... a[20479]
| socket 1    | core 5 | thread 5 | a[20480] ... a[24575]
| NUMA node 1 | core 6 | thread 6 | a[24576] ... a[28671]
|             | core 7 | thread 7 | a[28672] ... a[32768]
```

Now lets run another loop like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static,1) num_threads(8)
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   memset(&a[i*4096], 1, 4096);
```

Each thread will access the already mapped physical memory and it will have the same mapping of thread to memory region as the one during the first loop. It means that threads will only access memory located in their local memory blocks which will be fast.

Now imagine that another scheduling scheme is used for the second loop: `schedule(static,2)`. This will "chop" iteration space into blocks of two iterations and there will be 4 such blocks in total. What will happen is that we will have the following thread to memory location mapping (through the iteration number):

```
|             | core 0 | thread 0 | a[0]     ... a[8191]  <- OK, same memory node
| socket 0    | core 1 | thread 1 | a[8192]  ... a[16383] <- OK, same memory node
| NUMA node 0 | core 2 | thread 2 | a[16384] ... a[24575] <- Not OK, remote memory
|             | core 3 | thread 3 | a[24576] ... a[32768] <- Not OK, remote memory

|             | core 4 | thread 4 | <idle>
| socket 1    | core 5 | thread 5 | <idle>
| NUMA node 1 | core 6 | thread 6 | <idle>
|             | core 7 | thread 7 | <idle>
```

Two bad things happen here:

- threads 4 to 7 remain idle and half of the compute capability is lost;
- threads 2 and 3 access non-local memory and it will take them about twice as much time to finish during which time threads 0 and 1 will remain idle.

So one of the advantages for using static scheduling is that it improves locality in memory access. The disadvantage is that bad choice of scheduling parameters can ruin the performance.

`dynamic` scheduling works on a "first come, first served" basis. Two runs with the same number of threads might (and most likely would) produce completely different "iteration space" -> "threads" mappings as one can easily verify:

```
$ cat dyn.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (void)
{
  int i;

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
  {
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      printf("[1] iter %0d, tid %0d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());

    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,1)
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
      printf("[2] iter %0d, tid %0d\n", i, omp_get_thread_num());
  }

  return 0;
}

$ icc -openmp -o dyn.x dyn.c

$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./dyn.x | sort
[1] iter 0, tid 2
[1] iter 1, tid 0
[1] iter 2, tid 7
[1] iter 3, tid 3
[1] iter 4, tid 4
[1] iter 5, tid 1
[1] iter 6, tid 6
[1] iter 7, tid 5
[2] iter 0, tid 0
[2] iter 1, tid 2
[2] iter 2, tid 7
[2] iter 3, tid 3
[2] iter 4, tid 6
[2] iter 5, tid 1
[2] iter 6, tid 5
[2] iter 7, tid 4
```

(same behaviour is observed when `gcc` is used instead)

If the sample code from the `static` section was run with `dynamic` scheduling instead there will be only 1/70 (1.4%) chance that the original locality would be preserved and 69/70 (98.6%) chance that remote access would occur. This fact is often overlooked and hence suboptimal performance is achieved.

There is another reason to choose between `static` and `dynamic` scheduling - workload balancing. If each iteration takes vastly different from the mean time to be completed then high work imbalance might occur in the static case. Take as an example the case where time to complete an iteration grows linearly with the iteration number. If iteration space is divided statically between two threads the second one will have three times more work than the first one and hence for 2/3 of the compute time the first thread will be idle. Dynamic schedule introduces some additional overhead but in that particular case will lead to much better workload distribution. A special kind of `dynamic` scheduling is the `guided` where smaller and smaller iteration blocks are given to each task as the work progresses.

Since precompiled code could be run on various platforms it would be nice if the end user can control the scheduling. That's why OpenMP provides the special `schedule(runtime)` clause. With `runtime` scheduling the type is taken from the content of the environment variable `OMP_SCHEDULE`. This allows to test different scheduling types without recompiling the application and also allows the end user to fine-tune for his or her platform.

Comment: @HristoIliev if you set OMP_PROC_BIND=TRUE with dynamic schedule, would that preserve locality in memory access?

Comment: @Marouen, `OMP_PROC_BIND` prevents threads from being migrated from one CPU to another. That usually improves the locality for the case of predictable memory access patterns, e.g. with static loop scheduling. Dynamic scheduling usually leads to unpredictable access patterns and locality is rarely preserved, except for (thread-)private data..

Answer (score 31):

I think the misunderstanding comes from the fact that you miss the point about OpenMP.
In a sentence OpenMP allows you to execute you program faster by enabling parallelism.
In a program parallelism can be enabled in many ways and one of the is by using threads.
Suppose you have and array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

and you want to increment all elements by 1 in this array.

If you are going to use

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static, 5)
```

it means that to each of the threads will be assigned 5 contiguous iterations. In this case the first thread will take 5 numbers. The second one will take another 5 and so on until there are no more data to process or the maximum number of threads is reached (typically equal to the number of cores). Sharing of workload is done during the compilation.

In case of

```
#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 5)
```

The work will be shared amongst threads but this procedure will occur at a runtime. Thus involving more overhead. Second parameter specifies size of the chunk of the data.

Not being very familiar to OpenMP I risk to assume that dynamic type is more appropriate when compiled code is going to run on the system that has a different configuration that the one on which code was compiled.

I would recommend the page bellow where there are discussed techniques used for parallelizing the code, preconditions and limitations

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/

**Additional links**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP
[Difference between static and dynamic schedule in openMP in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261087/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-schedule-in-openmp-in-c)
http://openmp.blogspot.se/

Comment: Why would dynamic scheduling be beneficial on an unknown system? I believe you're missing the point as the biggest benefit is certainly better handling of an imbalanced iteration workload.

Answer (score 14):

The loop partitioning scheme is different. The static scheduler would divide a loop over N elements into M subsets, and each subset would then contain strictly N/M elements.

The dynamic approach calculates the size of the subsets on the fly, which can be useful if the subsets' computation times vary.

The static approach should be used if computation times vary not much.

Comment: Divide loop, did you mean the index of a loop?

Comment: If a loop is parallelized by OpenMP, then this happens having different threads operate on different portions of the loop, e.g. Thread 1 will operate on indices [0..32)[64..96), and Thread will operator on [32..64)[96..128).

Comment: Using schedule? Because if I just use a parallel for, the index will be shared, not?

Comment: No, the index should always be private to the thread, because each thread needs a separate counter.

Comment: I can divide que vector between threads? For example, I have a vector size 20. I want to a parallel bubblesort. So, I give 5 elements for each thread, and after all threads bubblesort, I merge all on a vector.
I' really confuse abaout schedule :(

Comment: No offense, but do you even know what OpenMP is all about? I think you should read some tutorials first, before attempting to bubblesort multithreaded.