# Labeling data for Bag Of Words

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp, pragma, labeling

I've been looking at [this tutorial](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/08/25/a-simple-object-classifier-with-bag-of-words-using-opencv-2-3-w-code/) and the labeling part confuses me. Not the act of labeling itself, but the way the process is shown in the tutorial.

More specifically the `#pragma omp` sections:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,3)
for(..loop a directory?..) {

   ...

   #pragma omp critical
   {
      if(classes_training_data.count(class_) == 0) { //not yet created...
         classes_training_data[class_].create(0,response_hist.cols,response_hist.type());
         classes_names.push_back(class_);
      }
      classes_training_data[class_].push_back(response_hist);
   }
   total_samples++;
}
```

As well as the following code below it.

Could anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What confuses you, the `#pragma` things?

Comment: Well I don't quite understand the different variations (ie `parallel`, `critical`), but also sheer amount of variables used that just aren't referenced in the tutorial (ie `class_`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pragmas are from `OpenMP`, a [specification for a set of compiler directives, library routines, and environment variables that can be used to specify high-level parallelism in Fortran and C/C++ programs.](http://openmp.org/openmp-faq.html#WhatIs)

The `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,3)` is a shorthand that combines several other pragmas. Let's see them:

`#pragma omp parallel` starts a parellel block with a set of threads that will execute the next stament in parallel.

You can also specify "parallel loops", like a `for loop`: `#pragma omp parallel for`. This pragma will split the for-loop between all the threads inside the parallel block and each thread will execute its portion of the loop.

For example:

```
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
  #pragma omp for
  for(int n(0); n < 5; ++n) {
     std::cout << "Hello\n";
 }
```

This will create a parallel block that will execute a for-loop. The threads will print to the standard output `Hello` five times, in no specified order (I mean, thread #3 can print its "Hello" before thread #1 and so.).

Now, you can also schedule which chunk of work will each thread receive. There are several policies: `static` (the default) and `dynamic`. [Check this awesome answer in regards to scheduling policies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852852/1259884).

Now, all of this pragmas can be shortened to one:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,3)
```

which will create a parallel block that will execute a for-loop, with dynamic scheduling and each thread in the block will execute 3 iterations of the loop before asking the scheduler for more chunks.

The `critical` pragma will restrict the execution of the next block to a single thread at time. In your example, only one thread at a time will execute this:

```
   {
      if(classes_training_data.count(class_) == 0) { //not yet created...
         classes_training_data[class_].create(0,response_hist.cols,response_hist.type());
         classes_names.push_back(class_);
      }
      classes_training_data[class_].push_back(response_hist);
   }
```

[Here](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/) you have an introduction to `OpenMP 3.0`.

Finally, the variables you mention are specified in the tutorial, just look before your posted code:

```
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
Mat response_hist;
Mat img;
string filepath;
map<string,Mat> classes_training_data;

Ptr<FeatureDetector > detector(new SurfFeatureDetector());
Ptr<DescriptorMatcher > matcher(new BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> >());
Ptr<DescriptorExtractor > extractor(new OpponentColorDescriptorExtractor(Ptr<DescriptorExtractor>(new SurfDescriptorExtractor())));
Ptr<BOWImgDescriptorExtractor> bowide(new BOWImgDescriptorExtractor(extractor,matcher));
bowide->setVocabulary(vocabulary);
```

Comment: in regards to your final point, there are still variables not mentioned, such as the one i said earlier (`class_`). Otherwise, awesome thanks

Comment: You're right. I can't help you with that, because I don't have experience with `OpenCV`. At the end of the tutorial you're reading, there's a link to the author's GitHub repository with the complete code. Check it out for the missing declarations!

Comment: Way ahead of you my friend ;)