# Are same lenght loop guaranteed to be separated the same way among OpenMP threads

Tags: multithreading, openmp

My question is simple, yet I'm not able to find the words to search the answer.

If I do this:

```
const unsigned N = ... ;
#pragma omp parallel
{
   unsigned i;
   #pragma omp for
   for(i=0; i<N; i++) // first loop
      <1st stuffs>

   <stuffs with other omp for...>

   #pragma omp for
   for(i=0; i<N; i++) // second loop
      <3rd stuffs>
}
```

Are the first and second loop guaranteed to be separated the same way among threads ?

If not, is there another possibility than defining the chunk size explicitly or using the schedule clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If certain conditions are met, then yes (OpenMP specification, Section 2.7.1 *Loop Construct*):

> A compliant implementation of the `static` schedule must ensure that
>   the same assignment of logical iteration numbers to threads will be used
>   in two loop regions if the following conditions are satisfied: 1) both loop
>   regions have the same number of loop iterations, 2) both loop regions
>   have the same value of *chunk_size* specified, or both loop regions have no
>   *chunk_size* specified, 3) both loop regions bind to the same parallel region, and 4) neither loop is associated with a SIMD construct.

The code in your example satisfies all four conditions, but you must **explicitly specify static scheduling** as the OpenMP specification leaves the default loop scheduling kind (i.e. the kind when no `schedule` clause is present) implementation-specific.

The following code is an example that is fully compliant:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp for schedule(static)
   for(i=0; i<N; i++) // first loop
      <1st stuffs>

   <other stuff>

   #pragma omp for schedule(static)
   for(i=0; i<N; i++) // second loop
      <3rd stuffs>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852852/7024081 the threads will indeed be assigned the same iteration ranges in both loops  assuming `# threads` and `N` are unchanged and that the scheduling is set to `static`.

If you can't set schedule to static I'm not sure what will happen as the default scheduling will be dependent on implementation: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#DO