# How to traverse two-dimensional vector by OpenMP

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new to OpenMP and got an error that I can't fix.

Suppose I have a two-dimensional vector:

```
vector<vector<int>> a{{...}, {...}, ...};
```

I want to traverse it as

```
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++){
        work(a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

However, there is an error: condition expression refers to iteration variable ‘i’.

So how can I traverse the two-dimensional vector correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the end condition of second loop depends on the first loop's index variable (`a[i].size()`). Only OpenMP 5.0 (or above) supports so-called non-rectangular collapsed loops, so if you use earlier OpenMP version you cannot use the `collapse(2)` clause here. Just remove `collapse(2)` clause and it will work.

Note that, if `a[i].size()` is the same for all `i`, then you can easily remove this dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However it has a bad effect when the fluctuation of a[i].size() is large. By the way, the version of OpenMP is 4.5, how can I upgrade it to 5.0.

Comment: Try to use different schedule schemes (e.g. schedule(dynamic) and different chunk sizes). More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850155/whats-the-difference-between-static-and-dynamic-schedule-in-openmp Unfortunately you cannot upgrade OpenMP version just the whole compiler. Clang based compilers support OpenMP 5.0, for more details see: https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/ ps: Do not forget to accept the answer if you find it useful, so others can see that your problem is answered