Issues when parallelizing for loop to perform array assignments
I am learning omp and came across this issue...
consider following code where:

Arrays a, b, and c are initialized

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static, 64)
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        d[i] = a[i];
        if( i + 1 < 256 )
            d[i+1] = b[i];
        if( i + 2 < 256 )
            d[i+2] = c[i];
    }
}

While running this code multiple times, following observations are noted:

Random results (correct/in-correct) are seen
in-correct values are assigned to d at index i=64 or i=128

Considering the number of threads assigned (4) and number of iterations (256), I applied schedule(static, 64) with chunk size 64. I am assuming scheduling with static will make the threads run in sequence. I even applied #pragma omp critical over assignments but that didn't work and random behavior persisted.

Please consider using OMP_NUM_THREADS instead of a hard-coded num_threads(4) which is a bad practice. Threads does not run in sequence, because otherwise it would not be parallel in the first place. Here, it defines which thread compute which items (i.e. partitioning).

I am afraid this loop is mostly sequential because of the d accesses. And even if it would not be a problem, a loop of 256 item copy is cheap (I assume copied objects are cheap) while creating threads and distributing the work is certainly more expensive than running this in sequential... Why do you want to parallelize such a loop in the first place?

Thanks for the suggestion using OMP_NUM_THREADS.. since i am learning omp so the loop size is not an issue here . just wanted to clear concepts doing small codes

Your schedule(static, 64) only tells that 256 iterations should be distributed in chunks of 64, but it doesn't determine which thread will be responsible for which iteration between threads in the team in a round-robin fashion (OpenMP-API 11.5.3 scheduleClause), and it doesn't guarantee that the threads will be executed in any fixed order. I found it nicely explained in these 2 articles:

OpemMP - scheduling
Programming Parallel Computers

So, you have a race condition + data race (thx Joachim). And you will still have these problems even if you add
        #pragma omp critical
        d[i] = a[i];
        if( i + 1 < 256 )
            #pragma omp critical
            d[i+1] = b[i];
        if( i + 2 < 256 )
            #pragma omp critical
            d[i+2] = c[i];

It means only 1 thread at a time is allowed to execute one of these 3 instructions. But consider that Thread1 doing iteration 69 is on the line d[i+1] = b[i]; and Thread2 doing iteration 68 is on the line d[i+2] = c[i];. Still race condition.

It's not only a race condition, but it is also still a data race (which makes the behavior undefined). critical, the Bazooka of synchronization is not even necessary, atomic write would be sufficient. But, also the d[i] = a[i] assignment would need the atomic write directive. This would fix the data race, as atomic writes sufficiently synchronize to avoid data race. The race condition persists, because the atomic write will not order the writes to the same variable, so each variable still can randomly have the value of a[i], b[i-1], or c[i-2]

Yep true, added this detail.

Both #omp critical and #omp atomic will make the loop so slow that it would not worth using multiple threads (even certainly on many-core CPUs). Atomics are nothing more than locks at a cache line level on all mainstream CPUs with an additional huge overhead compared to classical accesses (generally dependent of the number of cores so atomics on the same small portion of memory never scale).

Thanks for the reply mate .... I read the document which stated using schedule(dynamic, chunk_size) wont ensure the sequence in which threads shall run... whereas using static will make the threads run in sequence starting from Thread0, Thread1, Thread2, ... and so on .

I wonder how would be a race condition when in the docs it says using critical will ensure execution of all threads, exclusively . OMP is confusing me now

@ABUL_SALASA could you show us this document? OpenMP doesn't say anything about threads starting sequence, only about loop workload distribution. And EVEN IF starting sequence would be guaranteed, that still doesn't guarantee that they will finish in the same order. Related answer about scheduling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850586/4165552

@ABUL_SALASA OMP is not something that magically makes your code faster by running in parallel. You need to understand what you are doing and make sure that parallel work is distributed correctly without data races. #omp critical not something that you drop whenever you feel that results are inconsistent, if you need to use it, most likely your design is already flawed. As explained in my answer, putting 3 separate operations in the critical section doesn't make the overall algorithm race-free.

@ABUL_SALASA #pragma critical ensures indeed that the execution of the section is exclusive (in fact all section having the same name but all section of a parallel section have the same implicit name). However, "exclusive" does not means "ordered". Thus, the order of the section is left undefined even though two threads cannot write in the same item in parallel. This matches the definition of a race condition : the outcomes is dependent of the order of which the critical section execute.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-clauses?view=msvc-170#schedule
Please see the document which shows results in tabular form for each option (including dynamic and static) . My perception may be wrong about it, but the results seem to support my understanding about the concept.

the code snippet is not some serious project but just random lines only to develop understanding about omp, so flawness of design is not a point of concern here. however i highly appreciate  your responses and much valued guidance.

Mhmm oki, my bad, I found in OMP-API 5.2 document the following clause: "chunks are assigned to the threads in the team in a round-robin fashion in the order of the thread
number" - so this microsoft example is legit. Anyway, even with deterministic workload split, you still have a race :)

@JérômeRichard I don't agree with your statement that adding atomic will have significant performance impact for this specific code. Each value is only touched up to three times. Atomic is certainly not a lock at cache line level - unless you think of cache coherence in terms of lock? The main impact that atomic will have to this code is that the compiler will be limited in instruction reordering and will be forced to store the values to memory rather than keeping them in registers. There are only 3 cache lines that are shared between neighboring threads.

@Joachim On mainstream (x86-64 CPU)When you perform a classical store, the CPU check if data is in the L1 cache, if not there is L1 miss and the same happen with the L2, then L3 and DRAM (I assume a simple case where there is 1 CPU, 1 socket, and 1 NUMA node, etc.). Where there are multiple consecutive store, data can be prefetched and the CPU can pipeline the multiple independent stores. The fact that there are no other threads accessing cache lines is great for performance since most of the work can be done in the L1. In the end, each short native type store can take about 1 cycle.

@Joachim With atomics, this is a completely different story. Data is fetched from the shared L3 cache. Any access from another core results in a transfers passing by the slow L3 cache (having a latency of several dozens of cycles). The lock is indeed done at the cache coherence protocol level since cache lines are tagged as locked and only one code can modify a whole cache line at a time. Even when only one core does atomics, it is much slower (generally at least 10 cycles at best so 10 times slower).

@Joachim During atomic instruction (typically prefixed with LOCK), the CPU prevent any other memory accesses (typically by locking the bus). It also serialize the operations (it does not reorder them). On x86-64, all store to classical memory basically do a release memory barrier so this is not so critical (only the additional latency is). On ARM, memory barriers are more expensive. Thus, depending on the actual code used (kind of atomic) the overhead can strongly change.

@Joachim Here, data is probably not aligned and we do not know the size of items but lets assume this is 1 byte (worst case). False sharing will cause cache line bouncing and an heavy contention between core due to this hidden lock of the cache line. Each core cannot just modify a slice of the cache line but need to fetch it from the L3 in most cases, modify it before it is stored back and invalided again. This contention and L3 latency will make each memory accesses 10-100 times slower can classical stores. What matters is not the number of shared cache lines but the number of access to them.

@Joachim As for the L3 latency, generally, the higher the number of cores, the higher the latency (because of the interconnect/routing, number of directories, size, etc.). This is why atomics do not scale well with the number of core and do not scale at all when they access the same group of few cache lines (4-5 cache lines for 4 threads assuming 1 byte per item). Sorry for the long answer (this is a complex topic and there is a lot to say)  ^^" .

@JérômeRichard I completely agree with your writing for applications were multiple threads access the same memory with some contention. My argument was, that in this specific code, only a few (6) array elements will be accessed by different threads with 18 accesses in total. Even with single byte access, the neighboring thread would only write three times into the cache line mainly written by the neighboring thread (assuming cache-line aligned allocation of the array). E.g., thread 0 would write d[64], d[64], d[65] in its last iterations, belonging to the cache line written by thread 1.

@JérômeRichard Given the data race in the code, the compiler can generate code, where thread 0 loads the cache line starting with d[64], potentially containing uninitialized memory, into a register, executes d[64] = c[62];d[64] = b[63];d[65] = c[63]; and stores back the whole cache line from register. This can leave values d[66] onward in uninitialized state at the end of the for loop, if thread 1 wrote its data back before thread 0.

By adding OpenMP directives, you assert that the code will be free of data race when executing in parallel.
The code has a loop-carried dependence which will result in a data race during parallel execution. You can transform the loop easily into a dependence free (and therefore data race free) loop:
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{
    #pragma omp for schedule(static, 64)
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        d[i] = a[i];
        /* apply i:=i-1 to move the access to d into the same iteration */
        if( i < 256 && i - 1 >= 0 )
            d[i] = b[i - 1];
        /* apply i:=i-2 to move the access to d into the same iteration */
        if( i < 256 && i - 2 >= 0 )
            d[i] = c[i - 2];
    }
}

The comparison for the lower bound is necessary, as the initial code implicitly assumes i >= 0 based on the iteration space.
This transformation resolves the data race in the code without adding further synchronization. Compilers should be able to apply such transformation automatically and would actually perform such transformation to vectorize the code. Since you assert that such transformation is not necessary by using OpenMP, the compiler will not apply the transformation.
